# Adobe Livecycle - Highlight recommended fields when "Highlight Existing Fields" is active

Tags: pdf, adobe, livecycle

I have the following form in Adobe Livecycle

Not highlighted fields:
[image: Not highlighted fields]

Highlighted fields:
[image: Highlighted fields]

The two Phone fields are Recommended but I need an Orange border when "Highlight Existing Fields" is active.

The end result should look like this:

[image: Result]

**UPDATE:**
With "Highlight Existing Fields" I mean the button framed in red in the picture below

[image: Highlight button]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, **Highlight Existing Fields** can only highlight fields in one way. So if the field is required there will be a red border around it.

Alternatively, you can "switch off" the **Highlight Existing Fields** and control the look of the fields with tab/mouse/submit events.
If this is an acceptable solution here are 2 useful links:

[Failed fields are highlighted in an attractive way—without red borders](https://forums.adobe.com/message/5640759#5640759)

[Highlight field in response to user interaction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/10.0/DesignerScriptingBasics/WS92d06802c76abadb57cc1b6e12a92343946-7ff6.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer i'll give you +1 but i already found these links and I explicitly needed my given solution... So i can't accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Scripting for adding a orange border around a Phone 1 and Phone 2 fields**

In Adobe LiveCycle Designer select Firstname and Lastname fields and add the following scripts to each text field:

Add an enter event to the Firstname and Lastname fields:

```
Phone1.border.edge.color.value = "255,153,0";
Phone2.border.edge.color.value = "255,153,0";
```

Add an exit event to the Firstname and Lastname fields:

```
Phone1.border.edge.color.value = "255,255,255";
Phone2.border.edge.color.value = "255,255,255";
```

For more details see [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/designerHelp/index.htm?content=000842.html)

Comment: I think my question wasn't clear enough for you I updated it.
The orange border should only be visible if the button if pressed

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see how you can do that. It seems Adobe does not allow accessing this button event.